# (When Launching Python) CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFNSMono-Regular", it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font

Tags: python

When launching idle (Python 2.7) or idle3 (Python 3.7.5) from the Terminal I get several lines similar to the one below with different fonts as FONTNAME (".SFNSMono-Regular", ".SF NS Mono", ".sf ns mono") :

```
2019-12-18 10:11:00.317 Python[3676:16883] CoreText note: Client requested name FONTNAME, 
it will get Times-Roman rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be 
through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[NSFont systemFontOfSize:].
```

I also get a line with this :

```
2019-12-18 10:11:00.317 Python[3676:16883] CoreText note: Set a breakpoint on 
CTFontLogSystemFontNameRequest to debug.
```

I have already looked around and the only resources I found where from people developing their own apps. Some solved it by updating a third-party library that they identified by setting up a breakpoint as the second line type suggests.

This stems from Python (regardless of the version apparently), so how do I identify the source of the issue or set up a breakpoint as proposed?

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I don't see those errors on my setup, running Mojave with python 2.7 and 3.7.4.

Do you get the errors when you run IDLE from the Finder?

However, SFMono is not a system font, but a Resource of Terminal App. Are you using it as your Terminal font? Make sure that IDLE and Terminal are set to use a different font.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Launching from the Finder I don't get them but it does not surprise me as these errors did not show up in the IDLE window but in the Terminal window.

Maybe it is worth noting that I installed Python with Homebrew and not through the python.org package. I am running Mac OS 10.15.1.

Any idea how I can try to solve this? This is not a major issue but I would like to dig into it.

Comment: Do you have another Terminal app you could test? For instance xterm in XQuartz? 
I installed directly from the python.org download .pkg. I stay away from Homebrew if I can possible avoid it! ;-)

Comment: I have tried both on iTerm2 and Terminal and it is the same. I think can live with it. However, I am interested why do you say you avoid Homebrew if you can? I thought it was best practice to use it!

Comment: I just don't like the fact that you have to install loads of stuff, in order to be able to .... install loads of stuff. If I can just get complete individual installers for things I need, I much prefer that. I may be a lone voice in the wilderness.

Comment: @madamak There's definitely no reason to avoid Homebrew. It's a solid and well-maintained package manager.